# Import non exported javascript file with functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export, es6-modules

I have a package with some handy functions like

```
function func1() { ... }

function func2() { ... }
```

Then I try to import them via

```
import 'packagename'
```

But in my code below I cannot use `func1()` and `func2()` as they are `undefined`

Is it possible to import non `export`ed js code?

Comment: Whats the package? What are the functions?

Comment: recordrtc. There are 2 functions that I need: RecordRTC & setSrcObject

Answer (score 2):

You can see on the README of RecordRTC here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC#npm-install it has:

```
var RecordRTC = require('recordrtc');
var Whammy = RecordRTC.Whammy;
var WhammyRecorder = RecordRTC.WhammyRecorder;
var StereoAudioRecorder = RecordRTC.StereoAudioRecorder;
// and so on

var video = new Whammy.Video(100);
var recorder = new StereoAudioRecorder(stream, options);
```

To do the same thing via `import` you need to do:

```
import RecordRTC from 'recordrtc'
```